# is there any way to get singleton service without controller in .net core 2.0

Tags: asp.net-core-2.0

i use automapper to handle dto,now i create a singleton object like the picture .then i use the add function in Startup.cs to inject it.

[the inject function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T6Hzx.png)

in my application service,because of the Mapper is singleton,i want use it like a property from base ApplicationService.

[TaskAppService](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wo88g.png)

[ApplicationService](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yoFkI.png)

how can i get the automapper service in a single class.

i know i can use static property instead of the dependency inject.but i want to know it.

thanks for answer.

Comment: In general try not to post images of code. It makes it easier (and therefore more likely) to get help if others can easily access and copy/paste your code.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit confused on what you actually want but I'm going to go with you want DependencyInjection of Mapper.

In the Startup.cs, in ConfigureServices you could add a Scoped instance

```
services.AddScoped<IMapper, Mapper>();
```

This would allow you to inject **Mapper** in any constructor, which basically lets you use it as a service instance across your application.